# Is there any solution to this quadratic Diophantine equation?

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratics

Can one find all positive integer triplets $(x,y,z)$ satisfying this parametric equation :

$$ax^2 + (1-a)x + by^2 + (1-b)y = cz^2 + (1-c)z$$

Here, $a, b, c$ are positive integers greater than $1$.

$a≡1(mod$ $x)$

$b≡1(mod$ $y)$

$c≡1(mod$ $z)$

One solution is to write this equation in the form below?
$$X(X+A)+Y(Y+A)=Z(Z+A)$$
See Invid's answser : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142938/is-there-an-algorithm-to-solve-quadratic-diophantine-equations

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794510/curves-triangular-numbers   In this topic, written decision.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165805/is-there-any-solution-to-this-quadratic-diophantine-equation/165808#165808). To quote myself:

> If $c=0$, one has:
>   $$z=ax^2+by^2-ax-by+x+y$$
>   Which is obviously an integer.
>
> If $c\neq0$, then, we can rewrite the equation as
>   $$cz^2+(1-c)z-\left(ax^2+(1-a)x+by^2+(1-b)y\right)=0\\
> \implies z=\dfrac{c-1\pm\sqrt{c (4 x (a (x-1)+1)+4 y (b (y-1)+1)+c-2)+1}}{2c}$$
>   By using the quadratic equation.
>   We may set $x,y$ as integers. Then, $\left(x,y,\dfrac{c-1\pm\sqrt{c (4 x (a (x-1)+1)+4 y (b (y-1)+1)+c-2)+1}}{2c}\right)$ is the general form of the integer solution of the above equation ($c\neq0$) iff ${2c}\mid \left({c-1\pm\sqrt{c (4 x (a (x-1)+1)+4 y (b (y-1)+1)+c-2)+1}}\right)$. Any suggestions on simplifying this will be welcome.

Comment: Shouldn't this be closed as duplicate? I'm assuming that the OP are the same, since both are kiva2000

Comment: @CalvinLin It should be closed as duplicate, however you can't close $M.SE$ questions as duplicates of $MO$ questions.

Comment: This is such a joke answer perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I wasn't aware that we couldn't close as duplicates of MO.