# Diophantine eqn, general solution?

Tags: diophantine-equations

Here's the equation:
$$ 4 \left( x^2+y^2-z^2 \right)=\left( 2k+1 \right) \left( x+y-z \right) $$
Is there a nontrivial solution for this in integers?  If not, why not?  If there is, can a general solution be created?

Comment: Such equations there are always solutions. The formula can be viewed there.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794510/curves-triangular-numbers

Comment: $(k,x,y,z) = (70,0,-5,-5)$, $(142,0,29,29)$, and $(971,11,167,266)$ are solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x + y - z = u$ and $\eta = 2k+1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
& 4(x^2 + y^2  - z^2 ) = \eta(x+y-z)\\
\iff & 4(x^2 + y^2 - (x+y - u)^2) = \eta u\\
\iff & 4( -2xy + 2u(x+y) - u^2 ) = \eta u\\
\iff & 8(x-u)(y-u) = (4u-\eta) u\\
\end{align}
$$
As long as RHS of last expression is divisible by $8$, the last equation has solution.

Since $\eta$ is an odd number, we find $u$ itself is divisible by $8$.
Let $u = 8s$, the equation reduces to

$$(x - 8s)(y - 8s) = (32s - \eta)s$$

This means the general solution of the equation at hand can be parametrized as
$$
\begin{cases}
x &= 8s + p\\
y &= 8s + \frac{\Delta}{p}\\
z &= x + y - 8s = 8s + p + \frac{\Delta}{p}\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $s$ is any integer, $\Delta = s(32s - 2k - 1)$ and $p$ is any factor of $\Delta$.

For example, we can take $p = \pm s$ and obtain following two family of solutions

$$\begin{array}{lcrrr}
(x,y,z) &=& ( 9s, &  40s-2k-1,& 41s-2k-1 )\\
(x,y,z) &=& ( 7s, &-24s+2k+ 1,& -25s +2k+1 )
\end{array}
$$
which are available for any $k$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but anyway. A broad (but not complete) solution to,

$$x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = n(x + y - z)$$

can be given as,

$$n =p^4+p^2-1$$

$$x = p^2 - p - 1$$

$$y = p^2 + p - 1$$

$$z = 2p^2$$

Answer (score 0):

If there was a need for a simpler entry to the equation:

$$4(x^2+y^2-z^2)=q(x+y-z)$$

Then write a simple solution using any two integers - $k,t$.

$$x=(8k-1)t$$

$$y=qk-8k(4k-1)t$$

$$z=qk-(32k^2-8k+1)t$$

In this form it is easier and for all coefficients.

Comment: Simpler, short answers are always better, individ. When a complete answer is not needed (nor desired), 1 or 2 free variables are usually enough.