# Is there any solution to this quadratic Diophantine 3 variables equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Is it possible to find all positive integer triplets $(x,y,z)$ satisfying the parametric equation :
>
> $$x^2 + 2ax + y^2 + 2by = z^2 + 2cz$$
>
> Here $a, b, c$ are fixed positive integers.

Comment: For such equations the solutions are always there. The formula there.    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794510/curves-triangular-numbers

Answer (score 1):

One way to simplify a quadratic Diophantine is to get rid of *cross-terms* by doing a *linear substitution*. In this example, it is easy. Given,

$$x^2+2ax+y^2+2by = z^2+2cz\tag1$$

Let,

$$x,\,y,\,z = u-a,\,v-b,\,w-c$$

and it transforms to the simpler,

$$a^2+b^2-c^2-u^2-v^2+w^2=0$$

Since $a,b,c$ are constants, we can set $a^2+b^2-c^2 = d$, hence,

$$d-u^2-v^2+w^2=0$$

Do the further substitution $v,\,w =p+q,\,p-q$ to get,

$$d-4pq-u^2 = 0\tag2$$

I'm sure you can take it from here. **P.S.** All integer solutions of $(1)$ can be expressed in the form of $(2)$.

Comment: $$u^2+4pq = d\tag2$$

Could this be a part of the solution (from Zagier) ?

$$(u+2q,~q,~p-u-q),    if  u < p-q \tag2$$
$$(2p-u,~p,~u-p+q),    if p-q < u < 2p\tag2$$
$$(u-2p,~u-p+q,~p),   if u > 2p\tag2$$

Comment: w2 - v^2 = 4pk It's true if only w and v have same parity, othercase w2 - v^2 = 4pk + 1. We can also write u^2-a^2 = 4ef and c^2-b^2=4gh if u and a have same parity and c and b also.  In this cas we have 4pk+4ef+4gh = 0 => pk + ef + gh = 0