# do Pythagorean-triples have to satisfy the condition that is proposed by this equation?

Tags: number-theory

For any given three positive integers $a < b < c$ and  $n=2$ then 
it can be derived that

$$\frac{c^2 - ( a^2 + b^2 ) + {a+b-c}^2 }{ (c-a)(c-b)} = 2 $$

Then the condition $$\frac{(a+b-c)^2}{(c-a)(c-b)} = 2$$ to be satisfied to produce
the Pythagorean-triples.

Comment: I assume you intende $a^2+b^2=c^2$. There is a typo in the final condition; it should read $a+b-c^2$, with no parentheses. As stated, it always evaluates to a negative number (for pythagorean triples), so I wonder if a similar error crept into the first derivatoin?

Comment: It reminds curves triangular number. The formula there.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794510/curves-triangular-numbers

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish The typo is not in the final condition: it's the _first_ line which should be $(a+b-c)^2$ rather than $a+b-c^2$.

Comment: @user245958 What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,
your result
*does* hold for
any Pythagorean triple.
Here is the proof.

For relatively prime
Pythagorean triplets,
$(a, b, c)
=(2mn, m^2-n^2, m^2+n^2)
$
with $m > n$.

For this,

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{(a+b-c)^2}{(c-a)(c-b)}
&=\frac{(2mn+(m^2-n^2)-(m^2+n^2))^2}{(m^2+n^2-2mn)(m^2+n^2-(m^2-n^2))}\\
&=\frac{(2mn-2n^2)^2}{(m-n)^2(2n^2)}\\
&=\frac{4n^2(m-n)^2}{(m-n)^2(2n^2)}\\
&= 2
\end{array}
$

Comment: Sorry for leaving out parentheses;

Comment: In other words  (a+b-c)^2 / (c-a)(c-b) < 2 for all other sets of triples that obey ' a<b<c ' . is it OK?