# A ternary quadratic non-homogeneous diophantine equation in $\mathbb Z[t]$

Tags: diophantine-equations

I am interested in the diophantine equation in $\mathbb Z[t]$:

$$6Z^2 + 5((t + 1)X + tY − 1)Z +((t + 1)X + tY − 1)^2+ XY = 0$$
(the unknown variables are $X,Y,Z$)

Can one determine ALL the solution in $\mathbb Z[t]$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why? And why do you want all solutions?

Comment: This equation comes from the comptutation of the characteristic polynomial of a matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb Z[t]$. I am looking for all its eigenvalues in $\mathbb Z[t]$. I obtained this diophantine equation.

Comment: do you know any solution whatsoever?

Comment: The reason for asking about one solution is an approach specific to this dimension. It is pages 507-508 in Fricke and Klein book (1897) and written in an offhand way there. It is stated as a theorem in William Plesken, Automorphs of Ternary Quadratic Forms, pages 5-30 in Ternary Quadratic Forms and Norms, edited by Olga Taussky, 1982. It is theorem I.9 on page 15. It is at least possible that the same result holds over $\mathbb Q(t),$ which can then be adjusted to  $\mathbb Q[t]$ and  $\mathbb Z[t]$

Comment: If there was not $1$ it would be possible to use the formula.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794510/curves-triangular-numbers   Solutions of this equation are determined by the solutions of the Pell equations.  This formula exactly right? Because such a cumbersome formula nobody likes.

Comment: Yes, the equation is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the equation.

$$6Z^2+5((t+1)X+tY-1)Z+((t+1)X+tY-1)^2+XY=0$$

Can be written as an ordinary quadratic equation.

$$Z=\frac{-5((t+1)X+tY-1)\pm{D}}{12}$$

Where.

$$D^2=25((t+1)X+tY-1)^2-24((t+1)X+tY-1)^2-24XY$$

$$((t+1)X+tY-1+D)((t+1)X+tY-1-D)=24XY$$

The solution of this equation there.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215197/quadratic-diophantine-equation-in-mathbb-zt