# General Conic and its Rational Solutions

Tags: geometry, number-theory, diophantine-equations, conic-sections, rational-numbers

Suppose you have a rational conic $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$. There is a theorem that states if a conic has 1 rational solution it has infinitely many rational solutions. How can you prove this geometrically?

Comment: You had best typeset in the thing for which you want solutions. Also identify what particular theorem of Legendre is involved.

Comment: The same equation reduces to Pell's equation.    There solution is always there.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794510/curves-triangular-numbers

Answer (score 1):

A generic line intersects a conic in $2$ points.
If the conic and the line are rational (given by rational coefficients), then the set consisting of those two points is invariant by $\Bbb Q$-automorphisms, so either each point is rational, either they are defined over a quadratic extension of $\Bbb Q$ and the automorphism of that extension swaps the two intersection points.

If you have a rational point $P$ on the conic, then the rational lines going through it will intersect the rational conic at another rational point (possibly $P$ itself if the line is tangent at $P$ to the conic)

Moreover, two different lines going through $P$ can only intersect at $P$, so the lines that are not tangent to the conic at $P$ give you distinct points on the conic.

This actually gives you a birational map between $\Bbb P^1$ and the conic.