# Solving a multivariate quadratic equation in the integers

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratics

How can I find all integer solutions to the equation

$$ x (1 + 3 x) - y(3 + 3 y) - z(4 + 3 z) = 2?$$

I'm familiar with Lagrange's approach to binary quadratic equations, but am unsure how to deal with the third variable that appears in the above equation. Any progress towards a solution to this particular problem or references to a more general theory would be very much appreciated.

Comment: $x=X-1$ ; $x(3x+1)=(X-1)(3X-2)=X(3X-5)+2$ $$y(3y+3)+z(3z+4)=X(3X-5)$$  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794510/curves-triangular-numbers

Comment: I would start by collecting all the factors $3$ together, then $x-z-2$ is a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the equation by $12$ & arrange a little, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 36x^2+12x+1 =36y^2+36y+9 + 36z^2+48z+16 \\
 (6x+1)^2=(6y+3)^2+(6z+4)^2
\end{eqnarray*}
So it is just Pythagorus in disguise ... Eg $(3,4,5)$ gives $x=-1,y=0,z=0$ or ... more solutions can be generated using a deeper analysis modulo $6$ and using the usual parameterisation of pythagorean triples ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
 6x+1=-(a^2+b^2) \\
 6y+3=a^2-b^2 \\
 6z+4=2ab
\end{eqnarray*}
Now choose $a \equiv 2 \mod 6$  and $b \equiv 1 \mod 6 $ to generate more solutions ... Eg $a=8,b=1$ gives $(x,y,z)=(-11,10,2)$.