# How prove infinitely many postive integers triples $(x,y,z)$ such $(x+y+z)^2+2(x+y+z)=5(xy+yz+zx)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, vieta-jumping

> show that there exsit infinitely many  postive integers triples $(x,y,z)$
>
> such
> $$(x+y+z)^2+2(x+y+z)=5(xy+yz+zx)$$

May try it is clear $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$ is one  solution，and

$$(x+y+z+1)^2=5(xy+yz+xz)+1$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794510/curves-triangular-numbers

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma($\color{Green}{\text{Vieta's formula}}$)**:
Let $\alpha_1$ 
be the root of the quadratic **polynomial** equation 
$aY^2+bY+c=0$;
then we have: $\alpha_2= \color{Blue}{\dfrac{-b}{a}}-\alpha_1$.

**Proof**: 
Only notice that 
$\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = \dfrac{-b}{a}$.

---

---

$ 
\color{Purple} 
{ 
\text{Let's to look at one of the} 
\ \ 
x, y, z 
\ \ 
\text{as the} 
} $ 
$\color{Red}{\text{variable}}$ 
$ 
\color{Purple} 
{  
\text  {and to look at the others as} 
} $ 
**constants**.

---

For example let's to look at $\color{Red}{y}$ as an **indeterminate**, 
and to look at $x,z$ as **constants**;
as @user399601 has been done.

$$(x+\color{Red}{y}+z)^2+2(x+\color{Red}{y}+z)=5(x\color{Red}{y}+\color{Red}{y}z+zx) 
\Longrightarrow 
\\ 
\Bigg[ 
\color{Red}{y^2} 
+ 
\big(2(x+z)\big) 
\color{Red}{y} 
+ 
(x+z)^2 
\Bigg] 
+ 
\Bigg[ 
2 
\color{Red}{y} 
+(x+z) 
\Bigg] = 
\Bigg[ 
5(x+z) 
\color{Red}{y} 
+ 5zx 
\Bigg] 
\Longrightarrow 
\\ 
\color{Red}{y^2} 
+ 
\Big( 
2(x+z) 
+ 
2 
-5(x+z)
\Big) 
\color{Red}{y} 
+ 
\Big( 
(x+z)^2 
+ 
(x+z) 
-5zx 
\Big) 
=0  
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\Longrightarrow 
\\ 
\color{Red}{y^2} 
+ 
\Big( 
\color{Blue}{ 
2 
-3(x+z)
} 
\Big) 
\color{Red}{y} 
+ 
\Big( 
(x+z)^2 
+ 
(x+z) 
-5zx 
\Big) 
=0  
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\color{Green}{\star\star\star\star} 
$$

---

---

Suppose that 
$\color{Red}{y}$ 
satisfies the polynomial equation 
$\color{Green}{\star\star\star\star}$ 
;
then by 
$\color{Green}{\text{Vieta's formula}}$ 
; 
we can see that 
: 
$ 
\Big( 
\color{Blue}{ 
3(x+z) 
-2 
} 
- \color{Red}{y} 
\Big) 
$ 
will satisfies 
$\color{Green}{\star\star\star\star}$ 
.

So we proved that:

---

If 
$(x,\color{Red}{y},z)$ satisfies 
$\color{Green}{\star\star\star\star}$ ; 
then 
$ 
( 
x 
, 
\color{Blue}{ 
3(x+z) 
-2 
} 
- \color{Red}{y} 
, 
z 
) 
$ 
will satisfies 
$\color{Green}{\star\star\star\star}$ 
.

[ 
More specially if we let $x=1$ we have the following:
If 
$(1,\color{Red}{y},z)$ satisfies 
$\color{Green}{\star\star\star\star}$ ; 
then 
$ 
( 
x 
, 
\color{Blue}{ 
3z 
+ 
3 
-2 
} 
- \color{Red}{y} 
, 
z 
) 
$ 
will satisfies 
$\color{Green}{\star\star\star\star}$ 
. 
]

---

---

---

---

$ 
\color{Purple} 
{  \text  {This method is called}}$ 
$ 
\color{Green} 
{  \text  {vieta-jumping}}$

For more information you can see here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vieta-jumping

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping#Constant_descent_Vieta_jumping

Comment: I put an answer with the more complete Markov type tree.

Comment: @Will Jagy You are wellcome.

Answer (score 2):

This gives exactly the sort of jumping that creates the [Markov Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number) 
Since the order of $x,y,z$ does not matter, it is traditional to order $1 \leq x \leq y \leq z$ to save space. Then, we get two jumps that go to the next bigger layer in the tree. The slower growth is ( I am ordering the outcome as well)
$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto (x,z, 3x+3z - y - 2).  $$ The faster growth is
$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto (y,z, 3y+3z - x - 2).  $$
This diagram is closer to the view in the wikipedia article

[image]

The first few layers are

[image]

How do we find the relevant formulas for the next two leaves, coming out of an existing leaf $(x,y,z)?$  This part is called Vieta Jumping. We have an (positive) integer solution to 
$$ x^2 + (2 - 3y - 3z)x + \; \mbox{stuff} = 0. $$
If the $x$ value we have and the other solution to the quadratic is called $x',$ we have
$$ x + x' = 3y + 3z - 2, $$ so that
$$  x' = 3y+3z-x-2, $$ in ascending order we get $(y,z,x').$

If we are going to flip the $y $ value instead, we have
$$ y^2 + (2 - 3x - 3z)y + \; \mbox{stuff} = 0. $$
If the $y$ value we have and the other solution to the quadratic is called $y',$ we have
$$ y + y' = 3x + 3z - 2, $$ so that
$$  y' = 3x+3z-y-2, $$ in ascending order we get $(x,z,y').$

The best discussion of this that I know is a [1907 article by Hurwitz in German](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf). In preparing my article in this field with Kaplansky, I relied on  Cusick, Thomas; Flahive, Mari (1989). *The Markoff and Lagrange spectra.*

Answer (score 1):

If $(1,y,z)$ is a solution then $(1,z,3z-y+1)$ is also a solution because \begin{align*} &\quad \Big( 1 + z + (3z - y + 1) \Big)^2 + 2 \Big( 1 + z + 3z - y + 1 \Big) - 5 \Big( z + z(3z - y + 1) + 3z - y + 1 \Big) \\ &= (1 + y + z)^2 + 2(1 + y + z) - 5(y + yz + z). \end{align*} You can use this to generate the infinite family

$(1,1,1)$, $(1,1,3)$, $(1,3,9)$, $(1,9,25)$, $(1,25,67), ...$ of solutions.

Comment: how to find  $(1,z,3z-y+1) $ it?

Comment: @functionsug It was a guess, based on looking at some examples

Answer (score 1):

For the equation.

$$(x+y+z)^2+2(x+y+z)=5(xy+xz+yz)$$

It is possible to reduce the parameterization of the solutions to some equivalent to the Pell equation.

It has the form.

$$x=3a^2-(b+c)a+b^2-3bc+c^2$$

$$y=a^2-(b+3c)a+3b^2-bc+c^2$$

$$z=a^2-(3b+c)a+b^2-bc+3c^3$$

These parameters can be recorded through the solution of the equation Pell.

$$p^2-5(2k^2+t^2)s^2=-1$$

$$a=ks$$

$$b=p-(3k-t)s$$

$$c=p-(3k+t)s$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to more constructively get the answer user399601 provided:

Note that since $(x + y + z)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2(xy + yz + xz)$, the equation

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:constraint}\tag{1}
(x + y + z)^2 + 2(x + y + z) = 5(xy + yz + xz)
\end{equation}

is equivalent to

\begin{align*}
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2(x + y + z) &= (x + 1)^2 + (y + 1)^2 + (z + 1)^2 - 3\\
&= 3xy + 3yz + 3xz
\end{align*}

Now take $z = 1$ to get

\begin{equation*}
(x + 1)^2 + (y + 1)^3 + 1 = 3(x + 1)(y + 1)
\end{equation*}

Making the substitutions $u = x+1$ and $v = y + 1$, the equation becomes

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:simplified}\tag{2}
u^2 + v^2 + 1 = 3uv
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation*}
(u - v)^2 + 1 = uv
\end{equation*}

Now suppose there's some function $c:\mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $(u + c, v)$ is a solution whenever $(u, v)$ is a solution.  Then

\begin{align*}
(u - v + c)^2 + 1 &= (u + c)v\\
(u - v)^2 + 2c(u-v) + c^2 + 1 &= uv + cv \\
c^2 + 2(u - v)c &= cv
\end{align*}

So $$c(u, v) = 2(v - u) + v = 3v - 2u$$

Now note that if $(u, v)$ solves equation \eqref{eqn:simplified}, then $(u-1, v-1, 1)$ solves equation \eqref{eqn:constraint}.  Thus the solution $(3v - u, v)$ maps to $(3y - x + 1, y, 1)$.