# Solve $ \binom{a}{2} + \binom{b}{2} = \binom{c}{2} $ with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms, pythagorean-triples

I am trying to solve the Diophantine equation:

$$ \binom{a}{2} + \binom{b}{2} = \binom{c}{2} $$

Here's what it looks like if you expand, it's variant of the Pythagorean triples:

$$ a \times (a-1) + b \times (b-1) = c \times (c-1) $$

I was able to find solutions by computer search but this could have also been checked using the Hasse principle.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{3}{2}+ \binom{3}{2}&=& \binom{4}{2} \\ \\
\binom{5}{2}+ \binom{10}{2}&=& \binom{11}{2} \\ \\
\binom{15}{2}+ \binom{15}{2}&=& \binom{21}{2} 
\end{eqnarray*}

and many others.  Is there a general formula for the $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{Z}^3$ that satisfy this integer constraint.

---

```
>>> N = 25
>>> f = lambda a : a*(a-1)/2
>>> X = [(a,b,c,f(a) + f(b) - f(c)) for a in range(N) for b in range(N) for c in range(N)] 

>>> [(x[0],x[1],x[2]) for x in X if x[3] == 0 and x[0] > 1  and x[1] > 1 and x[2] > 1]

[( 3,  3,  4),  ( 4, 6, 7) , ( 5, 10, 11), ( 6,  4,  7), ( 6,  7,  9), 
 ( 6, 15, 16),  ( 7, 6, 9) , ( 7, 10, 12), ( 7, 21, 22), ( 9, 11, 14), 
 (10,  5, 11),  (10, 7, 12), (10, 14, 17), (10, 22, 24), (11,  9, 14), 
 (12, 15, 19), (12, 21, 24), (13, 18, 22), (14, 10, 17), (15,  6, 16), 
 (15, 12, 19), (15, 15, 21), (15, 19, 24), (18, 13, 22), (19, 15, 24), 
 (21,  7, 22), (21, 12, 24), (22, 10, 24)]
```

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1046687__

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794510/curves-triangular-numbers

Answer (score 8):

After some algebra you can rewrite the equation as
$$
a(a-1)=(c-b)(c+b-1)
$$

Note that $c-b$ and $c+b-1$ have opposite parity. Conversely, if $p$ and $q$ are integers with opposite parity, then we can find integers $b,c$ such that $p=c-b$, $q=c+b-1$: namely, $b=\frac{q+1-p}{2}$ and $c=\frac{q+1+p}{2}$.

That is to say, all solutions to the equation can be obtained in the following way:

- Choose some number $a$. Factor $a(a-1)$ into two numbers $p,q$ of opposite parity. Since $a(a-1)$ is always even, this just means $p$ and $q$ can't both be even.
- Take $b=\frac{q+1-p}{2}$, $c=\frac{q+1+p}{2}$.

For example, we could take $a=16$. Then $a(a-1)=240$, which factors into two numbers with opposite parity in four different ways:

\begin{align}
1&\cdot 240\\
3 &\cdot 80\\
5 &\cdot 48\\
15 &\cdot 16
\end{align}

These give four essentially different solutions to the equation:
\begin{align}
\binom{16}{2}+\binom{120}{2}&=\binom{121}{2}\\
\binom{16}{2}+\binom{39}{2}&=\binom{42}{2}\\
\binom{16}{2}+\binom{22}{2}&=\binom{27}{2}\\
\binom{16}{2}+\binom{1}{2}&=\binom{16}{2}
\end{align}

A few notes:

- Swapping $p,q$, or replacing them by $-p,-q$, gives a solution which is essentially the same if you remember that $\binom{n}{2}=\binom{1-n}{2}$.
- The symmetry between $a$ and $b$ means that this method will produce each solution twice. For example, the third solution above ($\binom{16}{2}+\binom{22}{2}=\binom{27}{2}$) could also have been found by taking $a=22$, $p=11$, $q=42$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ (2a-1)^2 + ( 2b-1)^2 = 1 + (2c-1)^2  $$

Taking any $c,$
if the right hand side is not twice a prime, there will be nontrivial $a,b,$ while factoring the right hand side gives a method for finding them other than raw search. So that is one approach.

Parameterizing all uses the modular group  $SL_2 \mathbb Z$: take integers
$$ \alpha \delta - \beta \gamma = 1.  $$ We also demand $\alpha \beta + \gamma \delta $ odd. This means that one of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ is even and the other three odd. Then

$$ 2a-1 =  \alpha \delta + \beta \gamma $$
$$ 2b-1 = \alpha \beta - \gamma \delta $$
 $$ 2c-1 = \alpha \beta + \gamma \delta $$

Yet another approach is the automorphism group of the quadratic form. However, see page 124 in Magnus, *Noneuclidean Tesselations and Their Groups*, where Lemma 3.7 shows that this group also depends on the modular group. Well, actually 3.33 and 3.34 on the next page, now that I look more carefully.

I ought to emphasize that $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0$ possesses a parametrization in just two variables, while $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1$ jumps immediately to four variables with a condition, namely the modular group.  Worth adding $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - w^2 = 0$ is naturally four variables, it is parameterized by the integral quaternions.