# If $T_n$ is the $n$-th triangular number, there are an infinite number of $a, b, c, d$ such that $T_n+T_{an+b} =(cn+d)^2 $ for all $n$.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers, triangular-numbers

If
$T_n$ is the $n$-th triangular number,
show that there are
an infinite number of positive integers
$a, b, c, d$
such that
$T_n+T_{an+b}
=(cn+d)^2
$
for all $n$.

This is inspired
by an article in the
current
Mathematics Magazine
(October 2019).

My calculations show that
the first two solutions are
(a, b, c, d)
=(1, 1, 1, 1)
and
(7, 8, 5, 6).

Comment: $$n(n+1)+(an+b)(an+b+1)=4(cn+d)^2$$  $n,b,d -  $ 
we set them as variables and unknown quantities and solve this Diophantine equation. For any number  $a,c -$ there are always solutions. You can use the formula.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794510/curves-triangular-numbers

Answer (score 2):

cleaner to use $\beta = 2 b + 1.$ Order as $(a,c,\beta,d) $
so that each separate variable obeys the same recurrence, with a dummy variable
$$ x_{j+2} = 6 x_{j+1} - x_j  $$

$$
\begin{array}{cccc|c|c}
a & c & \beta & d & 4cd-1& a \beta \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 3 & 1 &  3 & 3 \\
7 & 5 & 17 & 6 &  119 & 119 \\
41 & 29 & 99 & 35 & 4059 & 4059 \\
239 & 169 & 577 & 204 & 137903 & 137903 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: You clearly have done the same as I did, so I'll upvote but not accept since you didn't show how. Precision voting!

Comment: @martycohen your equation amounted to $a^2 - 2 c^2 = -1,$ then $(2b+1)^2 - 8d^2 = 1,$ finally $a(2b+1)+ 1 = 4cd. $ The recurrence I show above is Cayley-Hamilton applied to both relevant matrices, [3,4//2,3]  and [3,8//1,3]

Comment: I found it surprising that the Pell recurrences for the first two equations also applied to the third.

Comment: @martycohen sorry for delay. Probably messy to see in terms of separate linear recurrences. However, easy enough for the one-step mapping $$  (a,c,\beta,d)\mapsto (3a+4c,2a+3c,3 \beta +8d, \beta + 3d). $$ And it is interesting.