# Is Legendre’s solution of the general quadratic equation the only one?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, diophantine-equations, big-list

Legendre famously solved the general quadratic equation
$$
ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0
$$
by noting that
\begin{equation*}
4a(b^2-4ac)(ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f) = 0 \tag{$\star$}
\end{equation*}
along with the assumption $a(b^2-4ac) \ne 0$ forces $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$, while simultaneously implying the Pell equation
\begin{align}
 &\bigl((b^2-4ac)y-2ae+bd\bigr)^2 - (b^2-4ac)(2ax+by+d)^2  \\
  &\hspace{16em}= 4a(ae^2+b^2f+cd^2-bde-4acf). \tag{$\dagger$}
\end{align}

Evidently, we could substitute for ($\star$) *any* equation of the form $$k(ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f)=0,$$
where $k$ is some nonzero constant or function or set of variables, and thence derive another equation like ($\dagger$).

My question is, what other such “complete solutions” have been found?

Comment: this is about it. Complete the square in one variable by multiplying by $4a,$ there is still non-diagonal stuff left, so you do it again, this is the result. Finding the eigenvectors and center generally involves irrational numbers, no good for diophantine equations.

Comment: You can make $\dagger$ slightly more concise as,  $$(D y - 2a e + b d)^2 - D(2a x + b y + d)^2 = 4a(a e^2 + c d^2 - b d e + D f)$$ with discriminant $D = b^2-4ac$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Thanks! I do prefer the original, though, as it doesn't obscure the original variables.  =)

Comment: The general case actually yields ***two*** Pell equations. See this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1721471/transforming-diophantine-quadratic-equation-to-pells-equation). Also, a related [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580491/general-quadratic-diophantine-equation).

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: If you post an answer, I'll accept it and get this question off the Unanswered queue.