# Find all natural values n, that $\sqrt{P_{2}(n)}$ is also a natural number

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have a polynomial of the second degree $a\cdot n^2 + b \cdot n + c$ and I need to find out natural numbers $n$, such that $\sqrt{a\cdot n^2 + b \cdot n + c}$ is also a natural number.

After thinking about this problem, my idea was to rewrite it into $a\cdot n^2 + b \cdot n + c = x^2$ and rewrite it to look like a [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation):

$$(2an + b)^2 - 4ax^2= b^2 - 4 ac$$
which kind of resembles $x^2 - n y ^2 = 1$, but not really close enough to for me to solve it.

Then I tried to find some similarities in solutions for particular cases. For example when I took the equation $\sqrt{3\cdot n^2 - 2 \cdot n - 1}$ and wrote the program, the couple of first values were: `1, 5, 65, 901, 12545` (with no visible pattern for me).

---

So how should I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you really want to have a general solution that works for all values of $a,b,c$? If you are eventually only interested in some special cases, it would be easier to tackle those.

Comment: It's difficult to take your question seriously with that as your profile picture.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta if the general solution is too hard, you can show me how to come up with a solution for $3n^2 - 2n - 1$

Comment: If $c=k^2$ it is easy to rewrite in another Pell equation. In another case decided the same view through the Pell equation.

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049910___4    http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048216__

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have an infinite number of integer solutions to,

$$an^2+bn+c = d^2\tag1$$

but not necessarily all of them, then one way is, yes, to solve a *Pell equation*. First, as pointed out in the other answer, you need a initial solution. Second, if you limit it to only integers, then $a$ must *not* be a square.

Given an initial $n,d$ to $(1)$, then an infinite more can be found as,

$$ax^2+bx+c = (-d+py)^2$$

where,

$$x = n+qy$$

$$y = 2dp+(b+2an)q$$

and $p,q$ solve the Pell equation $p^2-aq^2 = 1$.

> **Example:**

$$3n^2-2n-1 = d^2$$

with initial $n,d = 5,8$, you get,

$$3x^2-2x-1 = (-8+py)^2$$

where,

$$x = 5+qy$$

$$y = 16p+28q$$

and $p,q$ is any solution to $p^2-3q^2=1$.

*Note*: This is an easy method to get an infinite number of solutions, but not all of them.

Comment: Any idea how can I find initial solution?

Comment: @SalvadorDali: You can use mod arguments like in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1335379/4781). Or, since it is the _smallest_ , then a simple program can quickly establish if it has a solution within a bound, say $|n|<1000$. If there is, the method above then guarantees there are an infinite more.

Answer (score 0):

With slight change of notation, you are looking for, given $a,b,c\in \mathbf{Z}$, points with integer co-ordinates on the curve $ax^2-y^2+bx+c=0$.

This is a conic. If you know one solution exists, then we can find infinitely many through rational parametrization. This is well-known (for example can be found in Silverman-Tate). Call this one solution point $Q_0$

Now  fix a line $L$ whose equations has integer/rational coefficients. For a
variable point $P\in L$ with RATONAL co-ordinates, write the equation of the line connecting $P$ with $Q_0$; as the intersection of a conic with line has 2 points you get the other point $P'$. This will be a rational point.(Convince yourself). So you get solutions you want.