# Reference Request: Quadratic Bivariate Diophantine Equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

I'm interested in Diophantine equations in two variables of degree up to 2; so

$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$

where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are integers and we are looking for all integer solutions.
All over the internet it is claimed that there is a general algorithm for finding all integer solutions of this, that was first described by Lagrange (this is claimed for example [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-79456-1_2) and  [here](http://www.numbertheory.org/PDFS/general_quadratic_solution.pdf), and [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation2ndPowers.html) about a more restricted equation). However, I wasn't able to find such an algorithm in any book on elementary number theory or on diophantine equations. Absurdly, even the book "Quadratic Diophantine Equations" by Titu doesn't have an algorithm for the full problem above! (obviously, it has algorithms for special cases.) The only source I found that claims it describes an algorithm is [this webpage](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/METHODS.HTM), but it is rather informal and I'd like to see a full proof in a serious book. Is there a book or (less preferably) a paper that describes the full algorithm?

Comment: FYI, a few closely related posts here, that you might find helpful, are [How to solve a bivariate quadratic (not necessarily Pell-type) equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1335360/602049), [Is Legendre’s solution of the general quadratic equation the only one?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/947000/602049) and [General quadratic diophantine equation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/580491/602049).

Comment: Another good post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1721471/transforming-diophantine-quadratic-equation-to-pells-equation

Comment: Page $57$ In Mordell's book Diophantine Equations.

Comment: Chrystal's Algebra, https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Algebra.html?id=_OiBvgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks a lot! Though old that's exactly what I was looking for. (Mordell's book doesn't really do this properly.)